# Alt+tabbing issue with games

Tags: nvidia, games, steam, lts

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with nvidia driver 495 on a 750Ti card.

Any steam game that I launch has the same issue - I can alt+tab, but cannot control my cursor. I can move it around, but nothing is clickable, seems to just hang/stuck. It's the same from native games, all the way to proton games.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Games may sometimes control the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key in specific ways. <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> in Ubuntu is also configured to switch tasks, and may work better.